# Using anchors to position nodes in a relational manner

Tags: tikz-pgf, anchor

Suppose that I want to create 3 tikz nodes named `a`, `b` and `c`.

The nodes should be positioned in the following relational manner:

First of all, `a`'s east anchor should be connected to `b`'s west anchor. Furthermore, `b`'s east anchor should be connected to `c`'s west anchor.

What is the correct way to do this?

I tried the following code (which doesn't work). I'm not sure what is wrong with my logic here.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle , draw](a){A};
\node[rectangle, draw , right of = a , anchor = west](b){B};
\node[rectangle , draw , left of = a , anchor = east](c){C};    
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: You have to draw the connections: `\draw[->] (a) to (b);`

Comment: Don't use [`right of=…` but `right=of …` from the `positioning` library](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386). Set either `node distance=0` or use `right=0 of a` then (same is true for `left` of course) then you can drop the `anchor` key.

Comment: The older syntax doesn't select the reference's anchor which lead to `a.center` to be the reference and not `a.west` or `a.east`. And you can't change that behaviour without extra work. → Use `positioning` with a zero node distance (either explicitly before `of` or implicitly via `node distsance`).

Comment: You could also manually do `[anchor=west] at (a.east)` which is what `right=0 of a` will do automatically for you.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways. Both produce the same output.

[image]

Using `chains`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain, node distance=5mm]
\node[on chain, draw](a){A};
\node[on chain=going right, draw](b){B};
\node[on chain=going right, draw](c){C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Using `positioning`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=5mm]
\node[draw](a){A};
\node[right=of a, draw](b){B};
\node[right=of b, draw](c){C};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

If you want to connect the nodes, you can add `\draw(a)--(b)--(c);` before the end of the tikzpicture. With chains, there is also the `join` option: `\node[on chain=going right, draw, join]`

[image]